# Hide Combo Box Border on Mouse Over

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have a DataGrid and one of DataGridColumns is defined as:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Width=".2*">
      <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
               <Grid Name="MyDMGrid">
                    <ComboBox Name="VersionCB1"  ItemsSource="{Binding cbValues}" SelectedItem="{Binding cbSelectedItem}"  IsHitTestVisible="True"
                                    Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=VersionCB}" SelectionChanged="VersionChange" MinWidth="20" MaxWidth="150" 
                                          HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,40,0" Foreground="Black" VerticalAlignment="Center" MouseEnter="VersionCB1_MouseEnter"  />
                                    
               </Grid>
          </DataTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

VersionCB Resource is defined in app.xaml as:

```
<Style x:Key="VersionCB" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="120" />
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="20" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                <Grid>
                    <ToggleButton x:Name="ToggleButton"
                        Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxToggleButton}"
                        Grid.Column="2"
                        Focusable="false"
                        ClickMode="Press"
                        IsChecked="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, 
                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite"
                        IsHitTestVisible="False"
                        Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}"
                        ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}"
                        ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}"
                        TextElement.Foreground="#FFF3F3F3"
                        TextElement.FontFamily="SegoeUI"              
                        TextElement.FontSize="14"  
                        Margin="3,3,23,3"
                        VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                    </ContentPresenter>
                    <TextBox x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox"
                       Style="{x:Null}"
                       Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxTextBox}"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                       VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                             BorderBrush="Transparent"
                             BorderThickness="0"
                       Margin="3,3,23,3"
                       Focusable="True"
                       Background="Transparent"
                       Visibility="Hidden"
                       IsReadOnly="{TemplateBinding IsReadOnly}" />
                    <Popup x:Name="Popup"
                         Placement="Bottom"
                         IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsDropDownOpen}"
                         AllowsTransparency="True"
                         Focusable="False"
                         PopupAnimation="Slide">
                        <Grid x:Name="DropDown" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" MinWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}"
                            MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}">
                            <Border x:Name="DropDownBorder" BorderThickness="1">
                                <Border.BorderBrush>
                                    <SolidColorBrush Color="Transparent" />
                                </Border.BorderBrush>
                                <Border.Background>
                                    <SolidColorBrush Color="#FFEBEBEB" />
                                </Border.Background>
                            </Border>
                            <ScrollViewer Margin="4,6,4,6" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" />
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </Grid>
                    </Popup>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
                        <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="MinHeight" Value="95" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsGrouping" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger SourceName="Popup" Property="AllowsTransparency" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="CornerRadius" Value="0" />
                        <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="Margin" Value="0,2,0,0" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I am seeing a border on combobox on mouse over as shown below:
[image]

I have tried following to get rid of the border. In VersionCB1_MouseEnter I wrote the following:

```
ComboBox cmb = e.OriginalSource as ComboBox;
cmb.BorderThickness = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0);
cmb.BorderBrush =System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Transparent;
```

But this does not work? How can I get rid of combo box border on Mouse Over?

Answer (score 0):

I think the border you are seeing is from `ComboBoxToggleButton` template.  I threw your code in a combo box to see if I could recreate the problem and I'm not seeing any border, but I had to remove the two references `ComboBoxTextBox` and `ComboBoxToggleButton` since I don't have them.

You could add the mouse over triggers to the toggle button control template to see if it is in control of that border.  I'm pretty sure it does.  I was able to control the mouse over border by adding the triggers.  I did a simple template to estimate what you have.  I was able to produce the desired behavior.

```
         <ControlTemplate
            x:Key="ComboBoxToggleButton"
            TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
            <Border
                x:Name="border"
                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                <ContentPresenter
                    x:Name="contentPresenter"
                    Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                    HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                    VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                    Focusable="False"
                    RecognizesAccessKey="True"
                    SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
            </Border>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Button.IsDefaulted" Value="true">
                    <Setter TargetName="border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}" />
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                    <Setter TargetName="border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
                    <Setter TargetName="border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                    <Setter TargetName="border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
```

[image: Screen shot of what I'm seeing]